# javascript : copying data from one array of objects to another which has existing data gives incorrect result

Tags: javascript, typescript

Copying data does not return correct results. This code looks fine, but it isn't giving me the results which are correct. Am I missing something? Looks as though it's using the same instance to copy the data into the object.

```
let sidList = [
    { taskTargetHosts: [['host1'], ['host1']] },
    { taskTargetHosts: [['host3'], ['host3']] },
];

let jobData = [
    { config: { tasks: [{ targetHosts: [] }, { targetHosts: [] }] } },
    {
        config: {
            tasks: [{ targetHosts: [] }, { targetHosts: [] }],
        },
    },
];

let dataIndx = 0;
for (let sidRow of sidList) {
    for (
        let taskIndx = 0;
        taskIndx < jobData[dataIndx].config.tasks.length;
        taskIndx++
    ) {
        jobData[dataIndx].config.tasks[taskIndx].targetHosts =
            sidRow.taskTargetHosts[taskIndx];
    }
    dataIndx++;
}
```

output expected for jobData:

```
    [{"config": {"tasks": [{"targetHosts": ["host1"]},{"targetHosts": ["host1"]}]}},{"config": {"tasks": [{"targetHosts": ["host3"]},{"targetHosts": ["host3"]}]}}]
```

What I'm getting:

```
[{"config": {"tasks": [{"targetHosts": ["host1"]},{"targetHosts": ["host1"]}]}},{"config": {"tasks": [{"targetHosts": ["host1"]},{"targetHosts":["host1"]}]}}]
```

Comment: Actually this code works fine - see: https://jsfiddle.net/7ppzz7xf/2/
Or do i missunderstand something?

Answer (score 1):

it seems to work for me your problem may be elsewhere

```
let sidList = [
    { taskTargetHosts: [['host1'], ['host1']] },
    { taskTargetHosts: [['host3'], ['host3']] },
];

let jobData = [
    { config: { tasks: [{ targetHosts: [] }, { targetHosts: [] }] } },
    { config: { tasks: [{ targetHosts: [] }, { targetHosts: [] }] } },
];




let dataIndx = 0;
for (let sidRow of sidList) {
    for ( let taskIndx = 0;     taskIndx < jobData[dataIndx].config.tasks.length;    taskIndx++ )   {

        jobData[dataIndx].config.tasks[taskIndx].targetHosts =  sidRow.taskTargetHosts[dataIndx];

    }
    dataIndx++;

}
console.log (jobData[0].config.tasks[0]); //{ targetHosts: [ 'host1' ] }
console.log (jobData[0].config.tasks[1]); //{ targetHosts: [ 'host1' ] }
console.log (jobData[1].config.tasks[0]); //{ targetHosts: [ 'host3' ] }
console.log (jobData[1].config.tasks[1]); //{ targetHosts: [ 'host3' ] }
```